# How do you add access keys (shortcuts) to a WPF ContextMenu, programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, shortcut

I already have the following:

```
var myContextMenu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();

var exitItem = new MenuItem();
exitItem.Header = "E_xit";
exitItem.Item.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(new System.EventHandler(ExitProgram));
myContextMenu.Items.Add(exitItem);
```

This causes my context menu to display the Exit menu item, with an underlined "x". However, pressing x does nothing. Clicking the menu item works fine.

How can I associate an event with the x key? Please note that this has to be done programmatically in my context. I cannot compose this solution in the XAML in front.

Comment: See if you can make use of the already build-in WPF commands via ApplicationCommands class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to add shortcuts is as follows:

```
var exitCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => ExitProgram());
        var exitItem = new MenuItem(); 
        exitItem.Header = "E_xit";
        exitItem.Command = exitCommand;
        myContextMenu.Items.Add(exitItem);

        InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(exitCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.X, ModifierKeys.Alt));
```

The [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) 
class used here is not the part of WPF but it's widely used in MVVM-based apps.

Please note though, that you cannot set your shortcut to X without modifiers.
Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture.aspx)

> In most cases, a KeyGesture must be associated with one or more
>   ModifierKeys. The exceptions to this rule are the function keys and
>   the numeric keypad keys, which can be a valid KeyGesture by
>   themselves. For example, you can create a KeyGesture by using only the
>   F12 key, but to use the X key in a KeyGesture it must be paired with a
>   modifier key.

If for some reason you need to use X w/o modifiers - you will have to handle keyboard events (eg KeyDown) and react accordingly

Comment: It is extremely common to see menus in windows (context menus or File menu, etc.), which have hotkeys without modifiers. Are these seriously all using keyboard events?

Comment: Can't say for sure, at least it is not possible using InpupBindings in WPF. Anyway, it's very easy to implement using keyboard events: private void mainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) { if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.X) App.Current.Shutdown(); }

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create menu item.
            MenuItem exitMenuItem = new MenuItem();
            exitMenuItem.Header = "E_xit";
            exitMenuItem.Click +=new RoutedEventHandler(exitMenuItem_Click);

            // Create contextual menu.
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            contextMenu.Items.Add(exitMenuItem);

            // Attach context-menu to something.
            myButton.ContextMenu = contextMenu; // Assuming there's a button on window named "myButton".
        }

        public void exitMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // This gets executed when user right-clicks button, and presses x down on their keyboard.
            // TODO: Exit logic.
        }
    }
}


<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="myButton" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The exitMenuItem_Click handler gets executed when the user right-clicks the button and presses 'x' on their keyboard. Are you not seeing this happen?

Comment: Correct, I am not seeing this. It may be worth noting that in my context there is no Window. I am creating a context menu for a system tray icon.